# PHP HmacSHA256() function not recognized

Tags: php, function

I have some code which is using this function and I get an error that the call is to an undefined function.

I am possibly using an older PHP version. Here is output of my phpinfo(): 
              **http://problemio.com**

But I am not sure how to do the equivalent of this function which is a requirement for some other service that I need to send the output to.

The code currently looks  like this:

```
$encoded_string_to_sign = URLEncode(Base64_Encode(HmacSHA256($string_to_sign)));
```

Thanks for your help,
 Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a built-in PHP function. You are probably looking for [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/hash_hmac) and an invokation like:

```
$hashed = hash_hmac("sha256", $data,  $key);
```

The code you are using possibly had a wrapper function defined or something.

(And from your `phpinfo()` output it seems that very `hash` extension is present.)

Comment: I edited the original problem. I am not sure what the $key parameter is supposed to be.  What is the key param? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a salt/key. You need one, otherwise it would be just a regular hash function, not HMAC. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Comment: is it something I have to get on my own? Or make it up? I just don't get its use in the function. What should it be? :)

Comment: You need to negotiate it with the message receiver. If you don't have any secret, then don't use HMAC.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) with `"sha256"` as the first parameter.

Comment: I edited the original problem.  How should it look now? I am not sure what the 3rd parameter is.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [mcrypt extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). Examples found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php).